# Error in Apache Hive regular expression

Tags: sql, regex, hadoop, hive, hortonworks-data-platform

I have a problem with a regular expression in hive, it does not recognize ";".

```
insert overwrite table prueba 
SELECT
regexp_extract(col_value, '^(?:([^;]*)\;?){1}', 1) VARIABLE,
regexp_extract(col_value, '^(?:([^;]*)\;?){2}', 1) TipoType
from temp;
```

The error that occurs is:

> H110 Unable to submit statement. Error while compiling statement:
>   FAILED: ParseException line 3:29 cannot recognize input near '^' ' (' '?'
>   In select expression [ERROR_STATUS]

Example Data:

```
VARIABLE;Tipo/Type;
FECHA;DATE;
ID_CLIENTE;CHAR;
CUS_TYPE;CHAR;
CUS_SUBTYPE;CHAR;
NUEVOTITU;NUMBER;
TITULAR;NUMBER;
BAJATITU;NUMBER;
.
.
.
```

Code:

```
drop table temp;
drop table prueba;
create table temp (col_value string);
LOAD DATA INPATH '/tmp/data/prueba.csv' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE temp;
create table prueba(variable string, tipotype string);
insert overwrite table prueba 
SELECT
regexp_extract(col_value, '^(([^\;]*)\;){1}', 1) variable,
regexp_extract(col_value, '^(([^\;]*)\;){2}', 1) tipotype
from temp;
```

Temp table:

```
temp.col_value
```

Prueba table:

```
prueba.variable prueba.tipotype
```

Comment: I guess there are no non-capturing groups in hadoop, use a capturing one instead: `(?:` => `(`. Try using `^(([^;]*);?)` with the limiting quantifiers.

Comment: the same error occurs, I am testing the expressions on https://regex101.com/ and is fine, but not hive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
SELECT
regexp_extract(col_value, '^(([^\;]*)\;){1}', 1) VARIABLE,
regexp_extract(col_value, '^(([^\;]*)\;){2}', 1) TipoType
from temp;
```

And if you need column values without ';' , use:

```
SELECT regexp_extract(col_value, '^(([^\;]*)){1}', 1) VARIABLE,regexp_extract(col_value, '(([^\;]*)\;){2}', 2) TipoType from temp;
```

EDIT: I have attached the screenshot. It is working fine on my system. Don't know why not executing on yours.

[image]

Comment: :( error        H110 Unable to submit statement. Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 3:27 cannot recognize input near '^' '(' '(' in select expression [ERROR_STATUS]                 
     thanks for your answer

Comment: sorry..try this...SELECT regexp_extract(name, '^(([^\;]*)\;){1}', 1) VARIABLE,regexp_extract(name, '^(([^\;]*)\;){2}', 1) TipoType from abc;

Comment: :( the same error occurredly, do not understand why not process the expression Hive. thanks very much for your answer

Comment: Are you trying it with insert statement included?? because it is working fine on my system.

Comment: @DiegoVL Can you post your create table temp and prueba query. As it is working fine with insert query included as well on my system.

Comment: @DiegoVL I have attached the screenshot. It is working fine on hive on my system. You may try restarting hive because it is not a problem with hive. :)

Comment: I used hortonwork, there may be a problem only graphic. Thanks for you answer

Comment: the only problem was graphic, thank you very much, your answer is correct.
:)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to escape the `\`,  so try this

```
^(?:([^;]*)\\;?){1}
```

Comment: no, the same problem remains.

Example data aggregate.

thanks for your answer